# Grouping elements in a list

Tags: python, list, grouping

I am working on joining dotted lines on any image. I have extracted and filtered the data samples.

This is my input data. In this dictionary, the keys '0', and '1' represents the x-coordinate and the list (values) represent the different y-coordinates for the respective x-coordinate.

Inside the list of different y-coordinates, I want to create a sub-list and store all the elements whose difference between two consecutive elements is less than 35. If the difference between two elements exceeds 35 then I want to create a new sub-list and repeat the same for next consecutive elements.

```
data = {0: [177, 188, 201, 209, 226, 233, 250, 258, 273, 282, 299, 307, 323, 330, 347, 355, 370, 379, 395, 403, 420, 428, 444, 452, 468, 476, 492, 500, 517, 524, 541, 549, 565, 573, 589, 597, 613, 621, 637, 651, 753, 761, 776], 1: [477, 489, 490]}
```

So the output would look like this.

```
data = {0: [[177, 188, 201, 209, 226, 233, 250, 258, 273, 282, 299, 307, 323, 330, 347, 355, 370, 379, 395, 403, 420, 428, 444, 452, 468, 476, 492, 500, 517, 524, 541, 549, 565, 573, 589, 597, 613, 621, 637, 651], [753, 761, 776]], 1: [[477, 489, 490]]}
```

How can I achieve the desired output?

Comment: So, if you see the values (177, 188), (188, 201),  (201, 209), and so on, their difference is less than 35. So I want to group all the values whose difference is less than 35. Similarly, if you take these points (651, 753), the difference is greater than 35. So, if the difference is greater than 35 then a new group should be created for the subsequent values.

Comment: That does not sound like an unambiguous criterion. Why not, for example, `[[177, 188], [201. 209], ...]` since the first pair has the difference 11 whereas the second has the difference 8, and 11 is different from 8?

Comment: Do you want me to elaborate further on this problem? My problem is to join dotted lines in a image. So, If I give very minute difference like 8, 0r 11, the gap between two dotted lines will not be joined together. That is the reason why I am giving a difference of less than or equal to 35.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for taking the time trying to solve my problem.

Comment: @TaarunSrinivas, it will be difficult for people to help with so little detail and no context. I'd try deleting this post and reposting your question with more detail, and perhaps the entire data set if possible

Comment: Maybe you're looking for image morphology, floodfills, watershed, clustering, ...?

Comment: Is the outer dict `{0: ..., 1: ...}` relevant, or can that be ignored?

Comment: @A.Salas I have clearly explained my problem statement. It is not possible to post the entire data set because there are more than 2000 data samples.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I have tried almost all image processing operations. None of the methods yielded a good result. That's the reason I started working at the coordinate level. Yes, the outer dict is relevant. The keys represent the x-coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1D "grouping":

```
def groupwhile(xs, key):
    group = []
    xs = sorted(xs)
    it = iter(xs)
    group.append(next(it))
    for x in it:
        if key(group[-1], x):
            group.append(x)
        else:
            yield group
            group = [x]
    yield group
```

```
>>> dist_10 = lambda a, b: abs(a - b) <= 10
>>> list(groupwhile([0, 7, 18, 19], key=dist_10))
[[0, 7], [18, 19]]
```

For 2D grouping, you'll need something more advanced for an efficient algorithm. Since you mentioned you're working with images, try something along the lines of image morphology, floodfills, watershed, or clustering.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This worked out well. For sure, I will try out the methods you have mentioned. Thank you.